# why lisp macro push only change symbol?

Tags: emacs, macros, lisp, push

In many lisp implementation, push is a macro look like this:

```
(push new list)
;; equal to 
(setf list (cons new list))
```

but setf cannot modify argument, like:

```
(defun add-item (new list)
  (push new list))
```

does not work, because function argument is not original symbol.

why not push work like this:

```
(defun my-push (new list)
  (setcdr list (cons (car list)
                     (cdr list)))
  (setcar list new)
  list)
```

Then push could work on argument of function.
Are there any reason make lisp push work this way?

*I'm only newbie to emacs lisp and sicp scheme.*

Answer (score 5):

One problem with your destructive `push` function is that it doesn't work on the empty list `nil`. That's a bit of a "deal breaker".

Note that the `push` macro, while it is an imperative construct which mutates the value of a storage location which holds the head of the list, it avoids mutating the structure of that list.

It is easy to reason about list processing code which uses `push` and `pop` over a local variable; you don't have to be concerned about possible bugs caused by mutated list structure.

Comment: nil condition can be avoid by some extra test.

Comment: @gholk: how so, if you don't have the variable accessible?

Comment: @gholk The problem is that `nil` is an atom which you cannot mutate. You cannot write a function `mypush` such that `(mypush 1 nil)` will turn `nil` into `(1)`. The function can certainly return that object,but then the caller has to capture that return value and update all the places which hold the list.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that *multiple* symbols (or other values) may be pointing at that list, or at sub-lists thereof.

If `push` worked the way you suggest, then you could change the values of more than just the specified symbol.

Consider:

```
(setq l1 '(foo bar))
(setq l2 (append '(baz) l1))
```

If you now 'push' to `l1` by manipulating the `car` and `cdr` of the cons cell that it points to, you would also modify the value of `l2`.

Of course there may be times when that is precisely what you want to do; however `push` is not the way to do it, and obviously you cannot redefine `push` to work that way without causing unwanted side effects in other code.

Answer (score 1):

There are several types of mutation. One is the object, where you can alter the `car` or `cdr` or a `cons` to something different. The `cons` will have the same address before and after so every variable pointing to it will point to the same, but the object gets changed.

```
(defparameter *mutating-obj* (list 1))
(defparameter *mutating-obj2* *mutating-obj*)
(setf (cdr *mutating-obj*) '(2))
```

Here you mutate the object so both variables still point to the same value that has changed. When evaluating any of them you see `(1 2)`.
Know that since we mutates objects the value can never be `()` in the beginning since it is not something with `car` and `cdr` that can be mutated.

With `setf` on a variabel you can think of variables as a address location to a value. Thus `setf` will mutate that location and not the value itself.

```
(defparameter *var1* '(1 2 3))
(defparameter *var2* *var1*)
```

Now we have two variables pointing to the same list. If I do this:

```
(push 0 *var2*)
```

Then `*var2*` has got its pointer changed so that it points to a new list starting with 0 and has the tail of the previous value. This does not change `*var1*` which still points the the previous value `*var2*` had.

When you call a function with a value the value gets bound as a new variable and doing `push` on it will do the same, alter that variable, never other variables that happen to point to the same value.

The common use for `push` is to start with an empty list and add elements to it. Setting `car` and `cdr` doesn't work for changing an empty list into a one element list with a given value. All variables pointing to `nil` will not have changed thus the method of using `rplacd` ( `(setf (cdr var) ...)` ) works if your data structure had a head element that is never used:

```
(defun make-stack ()
  (list 'stack-head))

(defun push-stack (element stack)
  (assert (eq (car stack) 'stack-head))
  (setf (cdr stack) (cons element (cdr stack)))
  stack)

(defun pop-stack (stack)
  (let ((popped (cadr stack)))
    (setf (cdr stack) (cddr stack))
    popped))
```

This however doesn't work unless you specifically design it so so `push` really needs to alter the variable and not the value since then it works always. (except for beginners who thinks it alters values)

Answer (score 0):

after google and read more code,
(like https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ListModification .)
I discover that lisp programer usually copy and modify the original list,
then assign it to the original list symbol.
maybe this is the style of lisp.

I am from javascript, which always modify original array,
but seldom copy it.
thank's for your answer.

Comment: Lisp has arrays too, if you need that behavior

Comment: Either it's safe to modify the original value, or it isn't. The language doesn't seem relevant.